# Is the Ising magnet relevant for magnets?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ferromagnetism

To what extent is the Ising model for the ferromagnetic transition experimentally relevant for real ferromagnets ?

For example if one quantitatively compares the magnetization versus temprature data rescaled by the critical points, do the data match with Ising scaling ?

Any hints to compilations of data or comparisons would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ising model is rather too crude a model to be of relevance to most real magnets. There are however systems well described by it (or by some suitable extensions); see, for instance, [*The Ising model and real magnetic materials*, W. P. Wolf, Braz. J. Phys. 30 (4), 2000](https://doi.org/10.1590/S0103-97332000000400030).

The Ising model is actually better as a model for a fluid, a binary alloy or an adsorbed monolayer at a surface, for instance... The fact that this model has a large number of physically completely different interpretations is a consequence of its very simple and generic form (Bernoulli random variables locally coupled with a quadratic interactions).

Of course, if you are interested in a specific magnet, then you'd probably need to incorporate a lot of additional structure to the model.